# How can I find non ascii strings in an array of strings, in Rails 2.0/ruby 1.8.6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

I have an array full of user logins that was loaded from the database.  What's the simplest and efficient way to keep only the logins that contain non-ascii characters?

```
logins = Users.find(:all).map{|user|user.login}
logins_with_non_ascii_characters = logins.select{ |login| ...??? }
```

Thanks

*Edit*: if you have a SQL solution (I use MySQL, but a generic solution would be better) to filter out the logins directly on the first line, with a :conditions clause, I'm ok with that too.  In fact, it would be way more efficient:

```
logins = Users.find(:all, :conditions => "...???").map{|user|user.login}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can abuse Ruby's built in regular expression character classes for this

[:print:] contains all ASCII printable characters.  It doesn't contain ASCII characters like beeps or, importantly, multibyte characters.

Working on the assumption that your users are unlikely to have ASCII BEEP as a character in their password,

```
#reject if has non-ascii character
valid_users = users.reject! {|user| user.login =~ /[^[:print:]]/}
```

should do it for you.

Comment: Incidentally, you can generate a list of printable ASCII characters like this `(32..127).map(&:chr).join`

Answer (score 2):

All I have found so far is this:

```
def is_ascii(str)
    str.each_byte {|c| return false if c>=128}
    true
end

logins = Users.find(:all).map{|user|user.login}
logins_with_non_ascii_characters = logins.select{ |login| not is_ascii(login) }
```

It's a bit disappointing, and certainly not efficient.  Anyone got a better idea?

Comment: Does it have to be efficient? It sounds like this is a one-time operation.

Comment: @John: Good point, it doesn't *have* to be efficient.  I just prefer efficient solutions, and I'm sure it would help me understand Ruby a bit better.  But in this case, this solution worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can select only login column from users:

```
non_ascii = /[\u0080-\uffff]/
logins = Users.select(:login).find_all {|login| login =~ non_ascii }
```

Or you can use `/\p{ASCII}/` in Ruby 2.0